# Trouble getting parameter from AJAX post method on the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

`id_estado` is coming **null** in the `cidade` controller

Is URL `$.post` parameter is calling correctly?

```
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
$(function(){
   $('#estados').change(function(){

        var id_estado = $('#estados').val();
        console.log(base_url+'ajax/Cidade/getCidades');
        console.log(id_estado);
        $.post(base_url+'ajax/Cidade/getCidades',{ 
            id_estado : id_estado
        },function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log('teste');
            $('#cidades').html(data);
            $('#cidades').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
   });
});
```

**getCidades**

```
public function getCidades() {

    $id_estado = $this->input->post('id_estado');
    var_dump('teste');
    var_dump($id_estado);
    echo $this->cidade_model->selectCidades($id_estado);

}
```

**selectCidades**

```
public function selectCidades($id_estado = null) {

    $cidades = $this->getCidadesByIdEstado($id_estado);

    $options = "<option>Selecione a cidade</option>";

    foreach($cidades ->result() as $cidade) {
        $options.= "<option value='{$cidade->id}'>{$cidade->nome}</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

**Error**

> Cidade.php
>   Line: 16
>   Call to a member function selectCidades() on null
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter3\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Comment: Welcome. Are `getCidades` and `selectCidades` part of the same class? Please show all relevant code, we can't guess where these methods exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the top of `getCidades()`

```
$this->load->model('cidade_model');
```

Comment: after adding this line and modify $.post to $.ajax right sintax it works, thanks

Comment: I would advice you add the loading of your model into your parent constructor rather than each individual method. otherwise it can get real messy very quickly :)